# Database tuning advices

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Possibly some of you don't even know about these features so you will learn a lot from this post which will in fact help me to optimize better and some of you probably use them on daily basis so you can help me and other less DBA proof users.

I'm using SQL-Server 2005 Standard

I run [SQL Server Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)r a lot. Each time i find ad hoc queries or sps which execution time exceed my possible limits of under 100ms for complex queries and above 30ms for short ones (number does not mean a thing, just to make some sense). After i find possibly problematic queries i write them down so i can use [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx) which executes overloaded queries on tables and at the result gives me indexes i need to build in order to improve performance. Each night i execute index rebuild function from Maintenance Plans.

Now question time!!!

1.if Database Engine Tuning Advisor gives me 10 indexes to create while improvement percentage is about 40% should i use it's advice or not? Better question is what is ratio number of indexes/improvement percentage i should follow. Indexes take space and time to rebuild.

2.If i create about 5-7 indexes for each problematic query, i can end up with 500 indexes per DB. How many indexes can i build so DB will perform normally? are there any limitations?

3.Is there any other way to optimize ( nor  re-design ) your DB other than using my method or going sp by sp by your hands and eyes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right answer to this question as it depends heavily on your workload.

For workloads with a heavy ratio of reads (e.g. data warehouse) it might make sense to create an index which it would be positively counter productive to create for an environment with a greater amount of writes.

The DTA can help with this regard by assessing the impact on the overall workload but you would need to try and capture a representative sample (not just the poor performing queries). SQL Profiler is quite resource intensive so to do this with the least possible impact on your server you would need to use a server side SQL trace with appropriate filters to only log events related to the database of interest.

To identify the poorest performing queries in isolation If you have at least SQL2005 SP1 client tools installed you should be able to right click the database node in Management Studio and use the Reports -> Standard Reports menu to see the plans in the cache with highest CPU/IO.

If you are interested in this area I recommend the book [SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Server-Performance-Tuning-Distilled-Experts/dp/1430219025) (most of it applicable to SQL2005 as well)

Comment: Reports seem to be disabled possibly due to Recovery Model set to simple... Thanks for the book, i like SQL the most out of all roles i have to cover at my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

You can get SQL Profiler to log to a table, so it will write the queries to a table you specify. If you can, leave it running for a few hours - Or however long it takes to cover as many queries/events as possible.

Next, use Database Engine Tuning Advisor - And get it to use this table of queries as its source input. You will find it looks at the whole pattern, and will recommend you create some indices, and remove others.

This is better than looking at queries one by one in isolation, although that still has its place.